# projectAs on original geometry vs part geometry

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I need to get XY and lengths of a part of a multipart feature in different CRS.  I can use the projectAs just fine when the it's the original feature geometry, but when I try to use it on the feature part, it doesn't do anything.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['NAME','SHAPE@']) as sc:
for row in sc:
    geometry = row[1]
    print "GeoType {0}".format(geometry.type)
    print "Orig Geo: {0}".format(geometry.firstPoint)
    print "Orig GeoPrj: {0}".format(geometry.projectAs(spatialRefSPNM27).firstPoint)
    geometryPart = geometry.getPart(0)
    print "Part Type {0}".format(arcpy.Polyline(geometryPart).type)
    print "Part: {0}".format(arcpy.Polyline(geometryPart).firstPoint)
    print "PartPRJ: {0}".format(arcpy.Polyline(geometryPart).projectAs(spatialRefSPNM27).firstPoint)
```

When I run that test I get this results.  Notice how projectAs works on the 3rd line but not on the 6th.

```
GeoType polyline
Orig Geo: -103.950469357 32.198115364 NaN NaN
Orig GeoPrj: 618430.281549183 436005.055399118 NaN NaN
Part Type polyline
Part: -103.950469357 32.198115364 NaN NaN
PartPRJ: -103.950469357 32.198115364 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geometry.getPart(0)` returns an array object with no projection. `arcpy.Polyline` doesn't set projection by default. `line.projectAs(somesr)` on line with no spatialReference data returns the same line. You have to reassign spatialReference when you create new line from part of your initial one.

```
import arcpy
from random import randint

# create polyline of two parts with 5 random points with WebMercator projection
part1 = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(randint(0,10**8), randint(0,10**8)) for x in xrange(5)])
part2 = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(randint(0,10**8), randint(0,10**8)) for x in xrange(5)])
wm = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)
line = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([part1, part2]), wm)
print line.spatialReference.name
# u'WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere'

line_part_1 = line.getPart(0)
try:
    print line_part_1.spatialReference
except Exception as e:
    print e
    # AttributeError: 'Array' object has no attribute 'spatialReference'
    # array doesn't have data about projection

newline = arcpy.Polyline(line_part_1)
print newline.spatialReference.name
# Unknown
# new polyline with WebMercator's coordinates still doesn't have projection data.

# solution:
sr = line.spatialReference  # save polyline SpatialReference
part = line.getPart(0)
newline = arcpy.Polyline(part, sr)  # new line with projection

wgs = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
projectedline = newline.projectAs(wgs)
print projectedline.WKT
# gives you something like MULTILINESTRING ((123.45721 76.125125, 56.87804 -12.23223, ...)) - line with coords in degrees
```

Comment: This was chosen as best answer because it explains the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Reassign your `geometryPart` variable to the projected geometry for the last print line.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['NAME','SHAPE@']) as sc:
for row in sc:
    geometry = row[1]
    print "GeoType {0}".format(geometry.type)
    print "Orig Geo: {0}".format(geometry.firstPoint)
    print "Orig GeoPrj: {0}".format(geometry.projectAs(spatialRefSPNM27).firstPoint)
    geometryPart = geometry.getPart(0)
    print "Part Type {0}".format(arcpy.Polyline(geometryPart).type)
    print "Part: {0}".format(arcpy.Polyline(geometryPart).firstPoint)
    geometryPart = geometry.projectAs(spatialRefSPNM27).getPart(0)
    print "PartPRJ: {0}".format(arcpy.Polyline(geometryPart).firstPoint)
```

Comment: I see, so projectAs the original geometry before making the part.  This avoids the missing CRS in geometryPart  issues which was mentioned by @Serge Norin.  This works and is a good option.